# Particle oscillating through a ring due to gravity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, newtonian-gravity

While looking through previous US Physics Team F=ma tests, I came across this interesting question that I cannot solve. The question is as follows:

A uniform circular ring of radius *R* is fixed in place. A particle is placed on the axis of the ring at a distance much greater than *R* and allowed to fall towards the ring under the influence of the ring's gravity. The particle achieves a maximum speed *v*. The ring is replaced with one of the same (linear) mass density but radius *2R*, and the experiment is repeated. What is the new maximum speed of the particle (in terms of *v*)?

I am convinced that this problem that has a simple solution, just one that I am not seeing. I do have the answer to this problem, which I won't reveal in this first post, but I don't have an explanation, or work. Keep in mind that this test is designed based on basic classical mechanics and is designed to be an algebra-based test.

---

Comment: I think if you calculate the gravitational potential at the center of each ring you will find it is identical. Thus a particle falling in gains the same amount of energy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the rings of the same mass, the force with the small ring at a distance $x$ is 4 times stronger than with a large ring at a distance $2x$. Energy is an integral of force over distance from zero to infinity. Using the symmetry described in the first sentence above, we can state that the energy with the small ring is twice the energy with the large ring (4 times the force by a half the distance with otherwise always the same geometry). Kinetic energy is proportional to speed squared, so the answer is that the speed is revese proportional to the square root of the radius.

You can also use a Pythagorus theorem and integrate for the same result:

$$E\propto\int_0^{\infty}\dfrac{dx}{x^2+r^2}=\dfrac{\arctan{\dfrac{x}{r}}}{r}=\dfrac{\pi}{2r}$$

You can use a similar logic to solve your problem for the rings of the same linear density.

Comment: So, for two rings with the same mass density, at the same distance the force would be doubled for the larger, leading to the same result?

Comment: No, you are missing the geometry. You need to have the same angle while comparing the rings. This means you can compare them only when the larger ring is at twice the distance. Compare the forces when the larger ring is at twice the distance.

Comment: So using this logic, the small ring has half the mass and half the distance of the larger one, leading to two times the force by half a distance, giving the same velocity for each ring?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. You can also see this from the formula by adding $r$ to the top part, because the mass is proportional to the radius. Then it just cancels out.

Comment: Alright. One last question - when you use the same angle for both rings, doubling the distance for the larger ring, doesn't this contradict the question? The question states that the same experiment is repeated with a ring twice as large, which I took to mean that the distance the particle starts at is the same for both cases.

Comment: The trick here is that energy is an integral of force over distance from zero to infinity in both cases. We are not comparing just at one distance. We are comparing at every distance from zero to infinity and integrating. So in both cases our integral is from zero to infinity, as required. However, using this symmetry (same angle, twice the dustance), we can say that in this case at every point from zero to infinity we have the same ratio. Therefore, regardless of the actual function, we can just by symmetry state that the ratio that applies at every point also applies to the whole integral.

Comment: If this logic is confusing, you can instead use the formula in the answer, just add $r$ that would cancel out in the end leaving a constant.